# Buying playing cards - probability

Tags: probability

You collect playing cards, in each package there is one of the $n$ playing cards one can get with probability $1/n$. How can one determine the expected number of packs you have to buy so that you pull one specific playing card two times, i.e. if there are playing cards $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n$, how can I determine the expected number of packs I have to get so that I pull $c_1$ two times?

Comment: Hint: the distribution for drawing a $c_1$ given that you already have a $c_1$ is the same as the distribution for drawing a $c_1$ given that you don’t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the negative binomial distribution to solve this problem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution Set up the random variable with the appropriate parameters, and then take its expectation.

You could also take the sum of two iid geometric r.v.’s to answer this. The expectation of the sum is the sum of the expectations. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: I obtain $2n$ as a result, does this seam reasonable?

Comment: @Jacob Yep, that's what I get also.